# How to insert text and html format data into a MySQL database via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

I have a problem inserting data (text and HTML format) into a MySQL  field LONGTXT.
Here is the error

```
  public 'error' => string 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''&lt;p&gt;

Haec subinde Constantius audiens et quaedam referente Thalassio doc' at line 1' (length=226)
```

error and almost clear. I used all the functions of protection (encoding format, quote, disabling html...)
I thought of another way, I created two functions dealing with commas, semicolons and slash.
Here is the code of the function addslashes:

```
FUNCTION addText($txt)
    {
        IF(get_magic_quotes_gpc()==false)
                {
                RETURN utf8_encode(addslashes($txt));
                }else{
                RETURN utf8_encode($txt);
                }

    }
```

protect commas function :

```
FUNCTION protect_virgules($txt)
    {
        IF($txt!='')
        {
            $x = strlen($txt);
            $newTxt = '';
            FOR($i=0;$i<=$x;$i++)
            {
                    IF($txt[$i]==',' || $txt[$i] == ';')
                    {

                        $newTxt.= '\\'.$txt[$i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $newTxt.=$txt[$i];
                    }
            }
            RETURN htmlentities($newTxt);               
        }
        else
        RETURN '0';
    }
```

insert php function :

```
 public function insert($table,$data){  
    
    $this->last_insert_id = NULL;

    $fields = "";
    $values = "";
    foreach($data as $fld => $val){
        $values .= trim($this -> escape($val)).",";
         $fields .= $fld.",";
         
    }
    $values = '"'.substr($values,0,strlen($values)-1).'"';
    $fields = '"'.substr($fields,0,strlen($fields)-1).'"';
    $tab=array($this->escape($table),$fields,$values,"@last_id");
    $this->CALL_SP("sp_insert",$tab);
    if ( $result = mysqli_query( $this->linkId, "SELECT @last_id AS last_inserted_id" ) ) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $this->last_insert_id = $row['last_inserted_id'];
        }
    }

    return  $this->queryId;
}
```

insert SQL proc code:

```
     BEGIN
 SET @stmt_sql=CONCAT("INSERT INTO ", tableName, "  (",fields,")VALUES(", param ,")");
 PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into last_id;
END
```

Syntax error always grabs me by the throat.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Post the actual SQL query which gets executed.

Comment: Also, try passing your data through `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: the function escape in php function ($values .= trim($this -> escape($val)... return string after using mysqli_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 3):

**Don't** `utf8_encode`, unless you want to convert strings from Latin-1 to UTF-8.
**Don't** use `addslashes` or depend on magic quotes; turn magic quotes off or use `stripslashes` to reverse their effects should you not be able to turn them off.
**Don't** manually replace and escape single characters, unless you have a very specific reason to.

**Do** escape *once* using the appropriate escaping mechanism for your database. If you're using `mysql_*` (don't use that anymore), use `mysql_real_escape_string`. If you're using `mysqli_*`, use <strike>`mysqli_real_escape_string` or better yet</strike> prepared statements. If you're using PDO, use prepared statements.

See [The Great Escapism (What you need to know to work with text within text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism) for a longer, more detailed discussion of the topic.

Your current "prepared statement" is useless, since it does not separate the query from the values at all. You're just concatenating all values as usual, then force them through a prepared statement in one go. There's also no need for a stored procedure, this can all be better done using the client-side API.

So:

1. Disable magic quotes [as explained in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).
2. Use prepared statements [as explained in the manual](http://www.php.net/mysqli_prepare).
3. Use `mysqli::insert_id` to get the last insert id [as explained in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).
4. There is no 4.

Comment: Yes, `PDO::quote` is the `_real_escape_string` equivalent for PDO. I would ***always*** suggest prepared statements instead of escaping though. You'd need a really good reason to use any escaping function if you have access to prepared statements.

Comment: first.. Thanks you for your reply.
deceze, i will try your recommendation .

Comment: You should never have to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you're using `mysqli` correctly. To even suggest it is misleading. Prepared statements are the most reliable way to ensure your data is properly escaped. Manual escaping has no business being in general application code.

Comment: I dont use PDO i use a classic method

Comment: Stop using this classic method. You're going to hurt yourself. Just **DO NOT**. Placeholders are *essential*. They are not to be ignored. Your example here is impenetrably complex and would be very difficult to audit. PDO provides a straight-forward way for expressing the same thing in fewer lines of code.

Comment: @AisthesisCronos You can use *real* prepared statements even with mysqli, even with *procedural* mysqli. Just do it.

Comment: @tadman Made my preference for prepared statements clearer in my answer. :)

Comment: @tadman i will do that in the future (other projects) because  currently, don't have permission to change :(

Comment: Good luck with that, then. The code you've posted here would fail any reasonable audit so it will have to be replaced eventually. Just make sure it's a liability that doesn't cost you. Have you tested it with a [SQL injection detection tool](http://sqlmap.org/)?